# How to synchronize MD5 digest between VTP Server and Client?

Tags: cisco, switch, vtp

Follow up to [this Q&A](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-can-i-force-vtp-clients-to-update-their-vlan-database-from-the-vtp-server-o).

According to one of the answers it should be possible to solve a MD5 digest mismatch by synchronizing username, password and domain between VTP Client and Server and subsequently executing a VLAN change on the VTP Server to align the MD5 digest on the Client.

However, after executing these steps and executing `sh vtp st` on both the VTP Server and the Client a discrepancy between MD5 digest between these two remains, which avoids that the VLAN database on the VTP Client is synchronized with the one of the VTP Server.

Once a name of a VLAN has been changed on the VTP server the MD5 digest will be changed. However, the MD5 digest on the client remains the same and the following message is shown:

`*** MD5 digest checksum mismatch on trunk: Po1 ***`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking [this thread](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/21771) on the Cisco Learning Network and subsequently executing some checks on both the VTP Client and Server, e.g:

```
sh vtp st
sh vtp password
sh int trunk
```

it appears that the `domain` is identical and the portchannel is in trunking mode. However, there was a discrepancy between the VTP passwords for some reason.

After synchronizing the passwords on the VTP Client and Server by executing `vtp password hello` and changing a name of a VLAN (`conf t` && `vl X` && `name helloworld`) on the VTP Server, the MD5 digests became identical

```
Switch#sh vtp st
VTP Version capable             : 1 to 3
VTP version running             : 1
VTP Domain Name                 : domain
VTP Pruning Mode                : Enabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
Device ID                       : X.Y.Z
Configuration last modified by X at Y Z

Feature VLAN:
--------------
VTP Operating Mode                : Client
Maximum VLANs supported locally   : 1005
Number of existing VLANs          : 6
Configuration Revision            : 6
MD5 digest                        : 0xfc 0x5e 0x03 0x8d 0x38 0xa5 0x70 0x32 
                                    0x08 0x54 0x41 0xe7 0xfe 0x70 0x10 0xb0
```

and the VLAN lists subsequently synchronized.

```
Switch>sh vl

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Gi0/1, Gi0/2, Gi0/3, Gi0/4
                                                Gi0/5, Gi0/6, Gi0/7, Gi0/8
                                                Gi0/9, Gi0/10, Gi0/11, Gi0/12
                                                Gi0/13, Gi0/14, Gi0/15, Gi0/16
                                                Gi0/17, Gi0/18, Gi0/19, Gi0/20
                                                Gi0/21, Gi0/22, Gi0/23, Gi0/24
                                                Gi0/25, Gi0/26, Gi0/27, Gi0/28
                                                Gi0/29, Gi0/30, Gi0/31, Gi0/32
                                                Gi0/33, Gi0/34, Gi0/35, Gi0/36
                                                Gi0/37, Gi0/38, Gi0/39, Gi0/40
                                                Gi0/41, Gi0/42, Gi0/43, Gi0/44
100  helloworld                       active
```

Answer (score -1):

Create one more vlan (you can delete it afterwards) and it should resolve your problem

```
add vlan 999
exit 
no vlan 999
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem?

Comment: @TeunVink it forces a refresh to the clients, if the config is the correct on both sides it will just syncronize