# Could MD5 digest be synchronized between VTP Server and Client if there is a discrepancy in Switch Versions?

Tags: cisco-ios, vtp

[image]

The MD5 digest between the VTP Server located on Switch1 and the VTP Client located on Switch2 have been synchronized.

Although the steps from [this Q&A](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9868/how-to-synchronize-md5-digest-between-vtp-server-and-client) have been followed, a trunk has been created between VTP Client Switch3 and VTP Server Switch1, a discrepancy in MD5 digest remains and the VLANs created on Switch1 do not appear on Switch3.

**VTP:**

*Switch1:*

```
Switch#sh vtp st
VTP Version capable             : 1 to 3
VTP version running             : 1
VTP Domain Name                 : domain
VTP Pruning Mode                : Enabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
Device ID                       : X.Y.Z
Configuration last modified by X at Y Z

Feature VLAN:
--------------
VTP Operating Mode                : Server
Maximum VLANs supported locally   : 1005
Number of existing VLANs          : 6
Configuration Revision            : 6
MD5 digest                        : 0xfc 0x5e 0x03 0x8d 0x38 0xa5 0x70 0x32 
                                    0x08 0x54 0x41 0xe7 0xfe 0x70 0x10 0xb0
```

*Switch3:*

```
Follows ASAP
```

**Trunk:**

*Switch1:*

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/X
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
```

*Switch3:*

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/Y
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
```

**Note:** trunk type is required on Cisco IOS 3560 and `encapsulation dot1q` is not available on Cisco IOS 2950

Comment: Can you post the output of "show vtp status" from both switches?

Comment: VTP Server configuration has been added. The other configuration follows ASAP as the switches reside on the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is no, the different switch versions don't matter.  As long as you're running the same VTP version on the server and client, both are configured for the same VTP domain and password (optional), and the link between switches uses 2 correctly-configured trunk ports, you should be good to go.

Comment: After synchronizing the VTP version it works with one trunk link